# How to find xpath in chrome Version 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit) using xpathfinder. shift+ctrl+x not working with

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, xpath, automation

CI'm not able to find xpath in Google chrome Browser Version 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit) using xpathfinder. shift+ctrl+x not working with this.

It would used with selenium 3.3.1 for automation testing.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

1) right click on the Element >

2) then select Inspect Element >

3) a small window will appear >

4) in small window on the Highlighted text under "Elements" tab, do Right Click

5) click copy >copy xpath.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Will this help you by any chance - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/relative-xpath-helper/eanaofphbanknlngejejepmfomkjaiic?hl=en